# How to prevent a specific request to redirect from http to https in SSL configuration?

Tags: ssl, java, https, jboss

I am facing one issue regarding ssl. Basically i want to stop redirection of only one request from http to https in Jboss 7.

According to the requirement all http request should be redirected to https but can we configure one url or request which should not be redirected https.

```
For example :- http://localhost/test/testId=1002
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding rewrite rules in ssl.conf file.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/testId=1002
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/test/testId=1002$1 [L,PT]

Add this rule and Restart your web server.